# How to press down a key?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Been using the pyautogui module to do most of my things, but I have come across one problem:

I cannot hold down a key for a certain length of time.

Does anyone know any modules that can do this, or have a solution without downloading any modules?
For example (perfect for me):

I go into word, and run my code. Word should just be receiving (w pressed down), with the w's slowly increasing - (after a while holding adds like 5 a half sec).

Comment: depends on how you want to use your key press

Comment: You can keydown, wait five second, and keyup again.

Comment: A quick search of the documentation: https://pyautogui.readthedocs.io/en/latest/keyboard.html#the-press-keydown-and-keyup-functions

Answer (score 5):

You can use the following example:

```
>>> pyautogui.keyDown('shift')  # hold down the shift key
>>> pyautogui.press('left')     # press the left arrow key
>>> pyautogui.press('left')     # press the left arrow key
>>> pyautogui.press('left')     # press the left arrow key
>>> pyautogui.keyUp('shift')    # release the shift key
```

In your case you'd use the `keyDown` function and a timer or equivelent to trigger `keyUp`.

You can find more information in regards to using timers [here](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/time.html#time.sleep) or better yet use [Timer](https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html#timer-objects) from the threading library - especially if you want to the processing to continue.

Example of using `threading.Timer` below.

```
def hello():
    print("hello, world")

t = Timer(30.0, hello)
t.start()  # after 30 seconds, "hello, world" will be printed
```

In the `keyDown` documentation one can note the following:

> NOTE: For some reason, this does not seem to cause key repeats like
>   would happen if a keyboard key was held down on a text field.

An alternative to using the `keyDown` function is to repeat the `press` function; in cases where `keyDown` is not satisfying the behaviour required by the developer and/or user.

```
def hold_key(key, hold_time):
    import time, pyautogui

    start_time = time.time()

    while time.time() - start_time < hold_time:
        pyautogui.press(key)
```

or

```
import pyautogui

while True:
    pyautogui.press('w')
```

*The above code is not tested.*

Comment: Example: I go onto word and run this code, it does not 'hold' the button but just types a's (im using keyDown(a) and press(a))

Comment: @IAmAlsoLearning if you do `keyDown('a')` and then `press('a')`, `press` will do `keyDown('a')` then `keyUp('a')` which will stop any repetition that Word(tm) performs. You just need to do `keyDown('a')`

Comment: @Peter Wood maybe its just my computer, but when I do keyDown, it doesn't 'hold' the key... Maybe some fix in my computer settings?

Comment: `keyDown` acts as if you hold the key down tangibly; meaning it will keep on printing 'w' over and over. - You can always try something on the lines of repeating the `press` function; added to the answer.

Comment: @IAmAlsoLearning I updated the story, I hope it helps you out.